Pass data from one block to another block as a request param in postman workflow
I’m new to postman flows and I need a help from you guys, I’m trying to pass the data from one block to another, the first block is successfully sending the data but the problem is within the second block it is not capturing the data correctly, i will provide you the whole flow in a picture below you can find it.enter image description here
The pass data is the value of body.responseBody from the first block which is a String “RANDOM12Aw” and it's need to be pass as a request param of the second block. I will provide the second block API as well in the form of picture, please check it once.
enter image description here
if you see the picture 2 it is the API for the block 2 and in the place of key i leave it blank cause it need to get the value form the block1. The problem here is the key is empty. The data is not retrieving properly,
Expecting a proper solution or the suggestions that can solve my problem.

Can you shows the response body of JSON for First POST API call?

{
"body": {
"responseCode": 201,
"token": null,
"responseMessage": "created successfully.",
"responseBody": "RANBOMwsdw12"
}

Thanks, based on your JSON. I made a mock server and flows.

This flow will work

Mock Server
demo.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/book-ride', (req, res) => {
    const responseJson = {
        body: {
            responseCode: 201,
            token: null,
            responseMessage: "created successfully.",
            responseBody: "RANBOMwsdw12"
        }
    };

    res.status(201).json(responseJson);
});

app.post('/find-nearby-drivers', (req, res) => {
    // Extract query parameters
    const pickLat = req.query['pickLat'];
    const pickLon = req.query['pickLon'];
    const ruidKey = req.query['ruidKey'];

    // Prepare the data to be returned
    const responseData = {
        'pickLat': pickLat,
        'pickLon': pickLon,
        'ruidKey': ruidKey
    };

    // Send the JSON response
    res.json(responseData);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});

Install Dependency
npm install express

Run Server
node demo.js

Define Environment Variables
dev
pickLat : 16.99807
pickLon : 82.24365


First API

URL
POST http://localhost:3000/book-ride

Tests tab
const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log("ruidKey: " + jsonData.body.responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("ruidKey", jsonData.body.responseBody);


After Press Send
ruidKey varaible will assign value by RANBOMwsdw12

Second API

POST http://localhost:3000/find-nearby-drivers?pickLat={{pickLat}}&pickLon={{pickLon}}&ruidKey={{ruidKey}}

After Press Send

Steps for Create Flows







I am happy to hear  you got it. Can you accept my answer? If you click up arrow in my answer. It will give me 15 points. Thanks!

sorry mate i did but i don't have reputations.

OK, After full understand my demo, try your case. If you shows more detail information. I can give an advice.

actually it is working.

Now can you give acceptance?
